# Avoid duplicates when migrating from one table to another

Tags: t-sql

I need to migrate data from an old Books table:

```
create table dbo.Books_OLD ( 
  Id int identity not null constraint PK_Books_OLD_Id primary key (Id),
  Title nvarchar (200) not null,
  Image varbinary (max) null, 
  Preview varbinary (max) null
)
```

To a new table structure:

```
create table dbo.Books ( 
  Id int identity not null constraint PK_Books_Id primary key (Id),
  Title nvarchar (200) not null 
)    

create table dbo.Files (
  Id int identity not null constraint PK_Files_Id primary key (Id),
  Content varbinary (max) null,
  Name nvarchar (280) null
)

create table dbo.BookFiles (
  BookId int not null, 
  FileId int not null, 
    constraint PK_BookFiles_Id primary key (BookId, FileId)
)

alter table dbo.BookFiles
add constraint FK_BookFiles_BookId foreign key (BookId) references Books(Id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
    constraint FK_BookFiles_FileId foreign key (FileId) references Files(Id) on delete cascade on update cascade;
```

The migration should run as follows:

```
Books_OLD.Title => Create new Book with given Title value
Books_OLD.Image => Create new File with Image content.
                   Create new BookFile to associate File to Book.
Books_OLD.Preview => Create new File with Preview content.
                     Create new BookFile to associate File to Book.
```

I was able to migrate the data but somehow when I run this:

```
select FileId
from BookFiles
group by FileId
having count(*) > 1;
```

I have duplicates. I should not have duplicate FileIds. What am I missing?

The migration code I have is:

```
DECLARE @BOOKS table (
  BookId int,
  Image varbinary(max),
  Preview varbinary(max)
)

MERGE Books AS d
USING Books_OLD AS s
ON 0 = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT (Title)
VALUES (s.Title)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, s.Image, s.Preview
INTO @BOOKS;

INSERT Files (Content, Created)
SELECT t.Content, GETUTCDATE()
FROM @BOOKS i
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (Preview, 'Preview'), (Image, 'Image')) t(Content, ContentType)
WHERE Content IS NOT NULL

INSERT BookFiles (BookId, FileId)
SELECT i.BookId, f.Id
FROM @BOOKS i
JOIN Files f
ON f.Content = i.Image

UNION ALL

SELECT i.BookId, f.Id
FROM @BOOKS i
JOIN Files f
ON f.Content = i.Preview
```

Some Books can have two files (Image and Preview) so BookId can appear more than once in BooksFiles.

But each file (Image or Preview) in Books_OLD table should only be associated with one Book. So it is strange that I have duplicated FileId in BookFiles.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have any same `image` or `preview` for different books?

Comment: @LONG In the Books_OLD table you can see that each Book has its own Image and Preview in its own column. But I am not sure if an Image or Preview is not the same in more than one book. But if it is how is my code doing that on migration? Maybe I am missing something ...

Comment: If the intent was not to let a book have one or more image/content then why move to this design?  Even if you fix this inset your database is not going to stop this problem in the future.

Comment: I have this design because I have many tables in the database that use Files so instead of having BookFiles with FK, PostFiles with FK and so on I have one centralized Files table. And in fact somefiles might be shared. However in case of the data I am migrating I want to create a new file for each Image / Preview in a Book and not have them being shared.

Comment: I just tested it and in fact in the Books_Old table I have a few rows with a same Image or same Preview. How can I change my code to solve the problem?

Comment: @MiguelMoura, please check the answer, see if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same `image` or `preview` for different book in your `Books_Old`, in your original code from this part:

```
INSERT BookFiles (BookId, FileId)
SELECT i.BookId, f.Id
FROM @BOOKS i
JOIN Files f
ON f.Content = i.Image
```

It will return you more results when doing the `INNER JOIN` because two `image` or `preview` from different books can be joined. And the duplicate `FileId` is actually a bad record, because the `BookId` is not correspond to that particular `Image` or `Preview` even though they are the same.

What you could do is have another table variable called `@Files`, similar to the `Files` table structure, you just need to add one more column, which is `BookId`, then:

```
INSERT BookFiles (BookId, FileId)
SELECT i.BookId, f.Id
FROM @BOOKS i
JOIN @Files f
ON f.Content = i.Image
AND f.BookId = i.BookId  --added joining condition
--assume code before has inserted bookId into `@Files`
```

So at last, you pick all the needed columns from `@Files`, insert them to `Files`.

**UPDATE:** please refer below for the full codes:

```
   DECLARE @BOOKS table (
  BookId int,
  Image varbinary(max),
  Preview varbinary(max)
)
--Added @File Variable
DECLARE @Files table
( 
BookId int,
Content varbinary (max) null,
Created nvarchar (280) null,
Id int identity(1,1) not null primary key
)  

MERGE Books AS d
USING Books_OLD AS s
ON 0 = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT (Title)
VALUES (s.Title)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, s.Image, s.Preview
INTO @BOOKS;

INSERT @Files (BookId,Content, Created) --
SELECT i.BookId,t.Content, GETUTCDATE()
FROM @BOOKS i
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (Preview, 'Preview'), (Image, 'Image')) t(Content, ContentType)
WHERE Content IS NOT NULL

INSERT BookFiles (BookId, FileId)
SELECT i.BookId, f.Id
FROM @BOOKS i
JOIN @Files f
ON f.Content = i.[Image]
AND f.BookId = i.BookId  --added joining condition

UNION ALL

SELECT i.BookId, f.Id
FROM @BOOKS i
JOIN @Files f
ON f.Content = i.Preview
AND f.BookId = i.BookId  --added joining condition

--Last insert all needed from @File into File
INSERT INTO Files (Content, Created)
SELECT content,Created
FROM @Files
```

PS: Not sure whether there is a typo for `dbo.File`, you have `Name` in your table definition, but when inserting, its `Created`

Comment: Sorry, I tried to integrate your solution into my code but I am probably missing something ... What about the previous block? Where it shows: CROSS APPLY (VALUES (Preview, 'Preview'), (Image, 'Image')) t(Content, ContentType)

Comment: @MiguelMoura check it now, may have some typos, but basic idea is that :)

Comment: there is something wrong with your code. Check this line: INSERT BookFiles (BookId, FileId) SELECT i.BookId, f.Id FROM BOOKS i JOIN Files f ... There is no Id in your Files table. Am I making sense?

Comment: @MiguelMoura, ah, yes, missed the `Identity` Id column, updated.

Comment: That was what I tried but when I run the code I get the following error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_BookFiles_Files_FileId". The conflict occurred in database "BooksNewDb", table "dbo.Files", column 'Id'. Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: The error was in line SELECT i.BookId, f.Id when inserting BookFiles and it fails to create BookFiles or Files after it but Books are created

Comment: @MiguelMoura, yes, that is because before `@Files` does not have `Id`, so `SELECT f.id` will throw error, I updated the `@Files` structure